# print report in sentence format in mysql

Tags: mysql, concatenation, mysql6

Being a newbie I need your help again. This time I'm trying to print a report in MYSQL 6.0 that shows each branch & its location in the following format: The 'branch name' is located at 'street address' in the city of 'city name'. I also need labels. Here's what I've done & gotten as a result:

```
SELECT CONCAT(name, ' ',  ' is located at', address, city, ' in the city of ')
FROM branch;
```

I got a column named address with 6 street addresses.

Comment: Can you post some sample data and then the desired result?

Comment: In a table named branch with data coming from 'name', 'address', and 'city', I want to show the name of the branch, it's street address, & name of the city it's in, so that it comes out in .sentence form, e.g. The Robinhood branch is located at 1234 Robinhood Rd in Salem.

Comment: you need to select only one record. Share the table schema please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, it sounds like you just want the following:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(name, ' is located at ', address,' in the city of ',  city) As Label
FROM branch;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80df0/2).

This generates a result of:

```
|                                                          LABEL |
------------------------------------------------------------------
| Robinhood is located at 1234 Robinhood Rd in the city of Salem |
|           New is located at 123 test dr in the city of Testing |
```